# Why is $Q(Z\notin N)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $(X_{n})_{n}, X$ be real random variables on probability space  space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ where $X_{n}\xrightarrow{d} X, n \to \infty$. Further let $(\Sigma, \mathcal{G}, Q)$ be a probability space where $Z$ is a random variable with standard normal distribution.

Show that

$Q(F_{n}(Z)\to F(Z))=1$

Let $N$ be the countable set where $F$ is continuous for all $x \in \mathbb R\setminus N$.

Why is it true that:

$Q(Z\notin N)=1$

I mean I know that $Z$ is continuous as it has standard normal distribution but the set $N$ is defined for $F_{n}$ and $F$... It has nothing to do with $Z$. I am not understanding something here, any idea?

Comment: The discontinuities of $F$ are countable. Have you seen this result before?

Comment: If you know that $N$ is countable, you can see that $P[Z \in N] = \sum_{x \in N} P[Z = x] = 0$.

Comment: What is $F_n$? What is $F$?